# Automating Development Environment Setup

Tags: scala, sbt

I've just started work at a new company and I am looking to automate as much as possible  their process to setup a development environment for new starters on their computers.

To setup a machine with a working development environment involves:

1. Checking out 4 different projects
2. Invoking maven to build and install those projects
3. Starting JBoss fuse
4. Running various windows bat files
5. Staring JBoss Portal

At the moment I am considering writing a script in Scala to do the above relying heavily on scala.sys.process. 
I am not too clued up on sbt at the moment and was wondering if that is better suited for this type of task or am I on the right track with writing my own custom setup script in scala.

Comment: sounds like a shell script would be much more appropriate. SBT is a build tool like Maven. What you need instead is something that runs a program, checks exit status and runs another task... etc. It should be easier to do in shell and perhaps Scala would not give you much in this case because you mostly use `scala.sys.process`.

Comment: This kinda stuff is usually done in shell scripts. Languages like ruby, python or perl are also popular for this. You can do it in scala if you want of course, I don't think there's really anything in sbt that'd help very much with this (you're just writing scala in sbt anyway)

Comment: Consider vagrant/fabric, this are established tools to solve this problem

Comment: Take a look at this [project skeleton](https://github.com/BTBurke/skeleton-vagrant-scala-sbt) which uses Vagrant and `sbt`. By the way [there is nothing wrong with choosing Scala for writing a script](http://www.scala-lang.org/what-is-scala.html) but reusing existing tools which are targeted for a specific scenario may make more sense.